# c++ multithreading: condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to multithreading. Here is what I want

```
thread_function(){
    // do job1;
    //wait main thread to notify;
    // do job2;
}
main(){
   //create two threads
   //wait both threads to finish job1
   //finish job3, then let both threads start job2
   //wait both threads to join

}
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Here is my code

```
void job1(){
}
void job2(){
}
void job3(){
}
int main(){
  thread t11(job1);
  thread t12(job1);
  t11.join();
  t12.join();
  job3();
  thread t21(job2);
  thread t22(job2);
  t21.join();
  t22.join();
}
```

My question is whether I can combine job1 and job2 to one function, and use condition variable to control the order?

Comment: The best way is to research a whole bunch, then write some code. SO is not your personal code writing service.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a sample (something similar to producer-consumer problem)
This is not the exact solution you are looking for, but below code will guide you,

Below "q" is protected by mutex, on which the condition variable waits for it to get notified or the !q.empty(needed for spurious wakeups) or time-out.

```
std::condition_variable cond;
std::deque<int> q;
std::mutex mu;

void function_1() {
    int count = 50;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        // Condition variables when used lock should be unique_lock
        // lock the resource
        std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
        // defer the lock until further 
        //std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu, std::defer_lock);

        q.push_front(count);
        locker.unlock();
        //cond.notify_one();
        cond.notify_all();
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        count--;
    }
}

void function_2(int x,int y) {
    int data = 0;
    while (data != 1)
    {
        // mu is the common mutex this resource is protected for the q.
        std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
        // this will only be done when !q.empty()
        // This will make sure it is handled by multiple threads
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        if (cond.wait_until(locker, now + y * 100ms, []() { return !q.empty(); }))
        {
            auto nowx = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            cout << "Thread " << x << "waited for " << (nowx-now).count() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Timed out " << endl;
            break;
        }
        data = q.back();
        q.pop_back();
        locker.unlock();
        cout << x << " got value from t1 " << data << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
     std::thread t1(function_1);
     std::thread t2(function_2,1,50);
     std::thread t3(function_2,2,60);
     std::thread t4(function_2,3,100);
     t1.join();
     t2.join();
     t3.join();
     t4.join();

     return 0;
}
```